# Reduction Factor of an Index Scanned Relation

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a relational schema as follows

```
Emp(eid: integer, did: integer, sal: integer, hobby: char(20))
```

It has `50000` distinct records, and a page can fit in `100` Tuples (which means there are `500` Pages).

It has a clustered `B+` tree index on `(Emp.did)` of size `50` pages.

If I were to do an Index Scan of EMP, and calculate the cost for it, I am confused as to what Reduction Factor should I utilize to calculate the cost of it?

Should it be `1/50000` or `1/50`?

Comment: What do you mean by "reduction factor"?  The only references that I see are to the ratio between the number of tuples in a result set and the number of tuples in the data being processed.

Comment: A formula for calculating the cost is like this: Cost = (NPages(I)+NPages(R)) * RFi, I am a little lost here about whether or not I should consider using 1/50000 at all times or thinking since it is an Index Scan I need to find something else/

Comment: What do you mean by `It has a clustered B+ tree index on (Emp.did) of **size 50 pages**.`

Answer (score 0):

Using a clustered index involved two cost parts:

1. Traversing the B-tree
2. Following the leaf node list to find all matching rows.

The principal formulas for IO Cost are (note the case difference: where #N=number of rows in index, #n = number of rows retrieved):

1. `log(#N)`
2. `#n/100`

Whereas the divisor 100 corresponds to the number of tuples per block.

The detailed calculation by actual databases typically considers more factors (most prominently CPU cost too) and might also involve some other heuristics (e.g., to represent cache/hit rate, fragentation or the like).

More about how indexes work: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy

Comment: Link inaccessible.

Comment: @L30n1d45 Link fixed. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, You got one decent blog.